# Remove Dolphin context menu entry 'Activities'

Tags: kde, plasma5, dolphin, kde-activities, servicemenu

On my plasma 5.24.6 I have this entry that seems deprecated, supposedly to create links for files and folders to an activity or other.

[image]

I couldn't even find what linking a file to an activity could mean. I was expecting something like opening that file/folder into a specific activity, restricting it to that activity -  but that's not it at all. ([For *that* window rules are needed.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/721738/341192))

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9xzlzm/comment/e9ybuyy/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) is the only meaningful info I could get: it should create  a link on the desktop in a given activity if the option was selected somewhere...

[Here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=126257) there is an old discussing showing this might have been dead since Plasma 5.2.

If this is true it seem like a deprecated feature, the option is absent in settings, and a google search gives nothing more.

Can I remove that buggy menu entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment by @fra-san: this is a context menu service. To disable it, just select "Settings" > "Configure Dolphin" > "Context Menu" and deselect "Link Files to Activities" (takes effect after Dolphin restarts).

[image]

Comment: Does it remove the extension or merely deactivates it?

Comment: @MaxN - Nothing "active" is deactivated nor removed, this just does what the question asks: removes (hides) the context menu *entry*. I guess it's just a service menu file like the ones we can edit at user level at `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus`, I'm not sure where it is located (cannot identify it at `/usr/share/kservices5`, otherwise I would have looked at the file to see what action it is supposed to involve: I have no idea what that is!), but surely we don't need and probably shouldn't remove/unistall anything.

Comment: @MaxN - In fact, based on the link in question, it seems that what this should have done is just to create a link on the desktop of a specific activity.